# Absolute definition of 'True' and 'False' in Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I searched for the definition of **Truth**.

According to this Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth ,

> Truth is the property of being in accord with fact or reality.

---

when I searched for the definition of **fact** and **reality**,

according to this Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact ,

> A fact is something that is true.

according to this Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality

> Reality is the sum or aggregate of all that is real or existent within a system, as opposed to that which is only imaginary.

---

So, I feel that this is not an absolute definition of 'True' and 'False'.

Is there a **logical derivation** of the definition of 'logical true' and 'logical false'?

Comment: In logic, the concept of "true in an [Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic))" is the fundamental notion. This notion may fit with the def above: "Truth is the property of being in accord with fact or reality." An arithmetic formula like $2=1+1$ is true in an interpretation based on *natural* number with their properties.

Comment: No "absolute" True and False.

Comment: "Logical true" may mean [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula) (aka: tautology).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "absolute definition". Can you provide any examples of definitions that you do consider to be "absolute definitions"? I'm even more confused when you ask for a logical derivation of the definition. Definitions don't have derivations!

Comment: @AlexKruckman in this video: https://youtu.be/3gBoP8jZ1Is , they have explained how "Numbers" could be defined by using concepts like set theory, function and equality (the Peano Axioms).  Similarly, I expected a definition for "True" and "False", which is built by using some foundamental concepts.

Answer (score 2):

When in real life we talk about something being 'True', we mean that it is the case in the world that we live in.  Thus, for example, we say that "Bananas are yellow" is True, but "I can swim across the Atlantic Ocean" is False.

So this is all compatible with the definitions you found on Wikipedia; this is all about facts and what is real: it's about *our* world.

In Mathematical Logic, however, we can contemplate any world we want. So there we can consider worlds where bananas are not yellow, but purple, or worlds where I can swim across the Atlantic. By 'any world we want' we mean any *logically possible* world ... basically an worlds that we can coherently imagine ... can you imagine a world where bananas are purple? Sure! But we may want to rule out worlds where a banana is both purple and not purple at the same time ... At least *classical* logic will say such a world is not logically possible.

So, many of these worlds are imaginary or idealized worlds. As such, whether some given statement is 'True' or 'False' in mathematical Logic depends on which of these worlds we evaluate the sentence in. That is, truth is *relative* to a world. The same statement can be True in one world, but False in another.

Indeed, logic (and much of mathematics, actually) really doesn't care so much about truth, as it cares about implication. So we say things like: Sentence $\phi$ implies sentence $\psi$, by which we mean: in all logically possible worlds , *if* $\phi$ is true, *then* $\psi$ is true as well.  So, whether statements are *actually* True (i.e. in our world), logic doesn't care about, but since it does care about implication, it needs to consider all kinds of worlds, and the truth-value of any statement can change between those worlds.

Finally, look at the link Mauro put in the first Comment to see how truth-in-a-world is dealt with in Mathematical Logic through the notion of an Interpretation. Lots of details there, though most of it deals with the syntactical and grammatical nature of the language of formal/mathematical logic. In the end, we simply take our basic/atomic statements, and we simply *declare* those to be true or false in our world (pretty much as a way to create that world in the first place) and go from there. There is really nothing deeper than that... which might make you a little disappointed, but hey, we need to start somewhere: if you keep asking why, you get turtles all the way down, and it'll never stop.

Comment: "I can swim across the Atlantic Ocean" is False."  I don't know your abilities.  But I think it's  possible that you could swim some distance in the Atlantic Ocean before drowning or heading back to shore.  Thus, I would say that under one interpretation, such a statement is true.  It's not true though, that you could swim across the entire 100% of the Atlantic Ocean from an eastern coast to a western coast.  You might though have the ability to swim across the Atlantic Ocean from one eastern coast to another eastern coast though.

Comment: ""Bananas are yellow" is True"  It's not true under the interpretation that "all bananas are yellow".  It is true under the interpretation "at least one hundred bananas are yellow." though. Haven't you seen an unripe green banana before?

Comment: I strongly disagree that logic doesn't care about truth.  If it did care little about truth, then contingent statements or false statements could function just as well as tautologies in axiomatic studies of logic.  If continent or false statements could function just as well as tautologies in axiomatic studies of logic, then all coherent statements would become provable.  And if logic didn't care about truth, soundness would not exist for logical calculi.

Comment: " ... we simply declare those to be true or false in our world"???  In propositional logic if you want to study classical logic or a subsystem of classical logic or even multiavlued logic, you want to have tautologies first or you have a big issue.  Ideally, that means one first checks for soundness or soon do later.  One checks that the rule(s) of inference is(are) valid.  One also checks that the selected well-formed formulas are tautologies.  Otherwise, a variable will be derivable.  And due to substitution or such as a theorem schema, everything would then become provable.